# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at AndroidPermissions.requestPermission

Tags: cordova, android-permissions, ionic4

I am trying to ask permission at run time. I am getting TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at AndroidPermissions.requestPermission ...

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';     

this.platform.ready().then(() => {        
this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then((data: any) => {
        if (data.hasPermission) {
            console.log("have permission");
        }
    });

})
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at AndroidPermissions.requestPermission (vendor.js:63232)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.139.HomePage.getPermission (main.js:75)
at main.js:67
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5134)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5125)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone looking for answer,

It was version issue updated android-permissions and core.

```
"@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.1.0"
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.1.0"
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-build-ionic-4-app-with-any-native-plugins-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-filetransfer/154197/6?u=samaludheen)

Comment: Yes, both should be the same version. For my case, I'm  still using `"@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0` so it works after downgrade to `"@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.20.0"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]).then(
    success => {
      this.presentToast("Has permission?  "+ success,"toast-warning")


    },
    err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
  );
```

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge of cardova.I am trying to resolve the issue.What is the version of android permissions native plugin you are using?

Comment: used updated version of android permissions native plugin

`npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions@^5.0.0-beta.14`

Comment: i am using `    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.0.0",`  let me try with this

Comment: @Samaludheen check this once - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/